# Encrypt something using SubtleCrypto and then decrypt it using crypto module

Tags: javascript, cryptography, encryption-asymmetric, subtlecrypto

Currently I have a request to change our client code from using nodejs crypto module to SubtleCrypto web API. The problem is, I am encrypting something using SubtleCrypto and asymetric encription (using public and private), but when I send the encrypted data to the server (which is using crypto module and I can't change it), I got an error like this:

`error:02000079:rsa routines::oaep decoding error`

How can I encrypt something using subtle.encrypt method and decrypt it using crypto.privateDecrypt method?

My encryption code looks like this:

`const encryptedArrayBuffer = await webcryptoAPI.subtle.encrypt( { name: 'RSA-OAEP', }, key, encoded );`

I expected the decryption works, but it looks like a compatibily problem between the two libraries.

This is the code I have on the client side (Next app). I don't have access to the BE server but I know they use crypto.privateDecrypt

```
const ASYMMETRIC_ALGORITHM = 'RSA-OAEP';
const ENCODING = 'base64';

async function importAsymmetricPublicKey(secretKey) {
  try {
    const publicKeyPEM = secretKey
      .replace(/-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----/, '')
      .replace(/-----END PUBLIC KEY-----/, '');

    const publicKeyBase64 = publicKeyPEM.replace(/\r\n|\n|\r/g, '');

    return await webcryptoAPI.subtle.importKey(
      'spki',
      Buffer.from(publicKeyBase64, ENCODING),
      { name: ASYMMETRIC_ALGORITHM, hash: 'SHA-256', modulusLength: 4096 },
      true,
      ['encrypt']
    );
  } catch (error) {
    console.log('[importAsymmetricPublicKey]: ', error);
  }
}

async function asymmetricEncryptStringKey(publicKey, generatedKey) {
  const key = await importAsymmetricPublicKey(publicKey);


  let encoded = encodeMessage(generatedKey);
  const encryptedArrayBuffer = await webcryptoAPI.subtle.encrypt(
    {
      name: ASYMMETRIC_ALGORITHM,
    },
    key,
    encoded
  );

  return Buffer.from(encryptedArrayBuffer);
}
```

Comment: *...but when I send the encrypted data to the server (which is using crypto module and I can't change it)...* Is this the Node crypto module? You'll need to show the relevant code on the server side.

Comment: Also post a complete and executable WebCrypto code including key import, plaintext encoding, etc.

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk  Yes it is Node crypto module on the backend and it is SubtleCrypto web API in the client

Comment: *...I don't have access to the BE server but I know they use `crypto.privateDecrypt()`...* This is possibly not enough. Your encryption code must match the decryption code. So you have to agree with the server side the details of the encryption/decryption, e.g. which padding is used, PKCS#1 v1.5 or OAEP? If PKCS#1 v1.5 is applied, this is not supported by WebCrypto. If OAEP is used, then you have to ask for the OAEP digests additionally. Currently you apply SHA256. You can try SHA1 on the off chance in the WebCrypto code (*crypto* uses SHA1 as default digest for OAEP).

Answer (score 0):

The problem with my current approach was I was using the wrong hash type. You have to use SHA1 as @Topaco mentioned.